# HOWTO: Fix "Cannot parse sensitivity level in s0" error when attempting to start a KVM VM after a major OS upgrade

Tags: rhel, kvm, qemu, selinux

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad T430 running Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.7 with kernel 2.6.32-573.8.1.el6.x86_64. This is a work computer and my corporate policy states that I must keep my operating system up to date, so I recently installed the aforementioned kernel version via `yum upgrade` (the upgrade also pulled over 100 updated packages), restarted, and now I was unable to start my VMs. Attempting to start one from `virt-manager` or with `virsh --connect qemu:///system list` throws an error message that says `error: internal error Cannot parse sensitivity level in s0`.

I eventually managed to fix this error as follows in the answer:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling around I found [this RHEL error report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=902103). Now, I know pretty little about SELinux but I do remember seeing a SELinux relabel taking place after upgrading my OS distribution, my SELinux issues casually happened after a kernel upgrade and the error report suggested trying a forced autorelabel by creating an empty file on the system root directory called `.autorelabel`.

So I created that file, restarted my computer, waited for the autorelabel to complete, and tried running a VM again. My VMs now start normally and the problem is fixed.